# Mod_write, htaccess and Wordpress slugs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is either blindingly simple or impossible; after lots of Googling and thread reading, I can't tell.

I have a WordPress site that uses a plugin to create a custom post type. The rub of this is that the custom post type has a very ugly "slug". What this means is that the URLs look like this:

http://mysite.org/uglyname/a-post-title/

Where "uglyname" is an ugly name. I can't change the name without editing the core files of the plugin, which is a bad idea in this context.

What I'd like to do is make it so that if a user visits a URL like this:

http://mysite.org/prettyname/a-post-title/

Wordpress interprets prettyname as it would uglyname and is more or less nonethewiser.

I don't want something that just redirects; I'd like it to be a silent mapping. But keep in mind that Wordpress is already using the .htaccess file to map everything it gets onto http://mysite.org/index.php.

Is this possible, or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

EDIT to add: The current .htaccess is the WordPress default:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite.org/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite.org/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Give us current .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Just above `RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, try the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^prettyname/(.+)/? /uglyname/$1
```

If I'm not mistaken, it should pass it over, and then still process the `index.php` routing.

Haven't tested it - not at a server right now.